# Learning more about APOPT solver

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming, gekko

I have a few questions about how APOPT solves MINLPs.

- What nonlinear programming method APOPT uses (interior point, trust region, etc.)?
- How does APOPT deal with mixed integers (B&B, outer approximation,  generalized benders decomposition,etc)?

Answer (score 5):

APOPT is an active-set Sequential Quadratic Programming (SQP) solver that uses Branch and Bound. APOPT uses a warm-start method to speed up successive Nonlinear Programming (NLP) solutions. There is more information about APOPT from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APOPT), [APMonitor documentation](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmSolver), and [APOPT.com](https://apopt.com). There is benchmark information from a 2013 INFORMS presentation and in the 2014 APMonitor CACE paper.

1. Hedengren, J.D., Mojica, J.L., Lewis, A.D. and Nikbakhsh, S., [MINLP with Combined Interior Point and Active Set Methods](https://apm.byu.edu/prism/uploads/Members/apopt_minlp_presentation_informs2013.pdf), INFORMS Annual Meeting, Minneapolis, MN, Oct 2013.
2. Hedengren, J. D. and Asgharzadeh Shishavan, R., Powell, K.M., and Edgar, T.F., [Nonlinear Modeling, Estimation and Predictive Control in APMonitor](http://apmonitor.com/wiki/uploads/Main/APMonitor_2014.pdf), Computers and Chemical Engineering, Volume 70, pg. 133–148, 2014, doi: 10.1016/j.compchemeng.2014.04.013.

Here is a sample MINLP problem solved with Python Gekko after getting the package with `pip install gekko`

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO() # Initialize gekko
m.options.SOLVER=1  # APOPT is an MINLP solver

# optional solver settings with APOPT
m.solver_options = ['minlp_maximum_iterations 500', \
                    # minlp iterations with integer solution
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 10', \
                    # treat minlp as nlp
                    'minlp_as_nlp 0', \
                    # nlp sub-problem max iterations
                    'nlp_maximum_iterations 50', \
                    # 1 = depth first, 2 = breadth first
                    'minlp_branch_method 1', \
                    # maximum deviation from whole number
                    'minlp_integer_tol 0.05', \
                    # covergence tolerance
                    'minlp_gap_tol 0.01']
# Initialize variables
x1 = m.Var(value=1,lb=1,ub=5)
x2 = m.Var(value=5,lb=1,ub=5)
# Integer constraints for x3 and x4
x3 = m.Var(value=5,lb=1,ub=5,integer=True)
x4 = m.Var(value=1,lb=1,ub=5,integer=True)
m.Equation(x1*x2*x3*x4>=25)
m.Equation(x1**2+x2**2+x3**2+x4**2==40)
m.Obj(x1*x4*(x1+x2+x3)+x3) # Objective
m.solve(disp=False) # Solve
print('x1: ' + str(x1.value))
print('x2: ' + str(x2.value))
print('x3: ' + str(x3.value))
print('x4: ' + str(x4.value))
print('Objective: ' + str(m.options.objfcnval))
```

The iteration summary gives more information about the branch and bound process to find the solution.

```
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    7 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    3 Obj:  1.70E+01 Gap:       NaN
--Integer Solution:   1.75E+01 Lowest Leaf:   1.70E+01 Gap:   3.00E-02
Iter:     2 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    5 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    2 Obj:  1.75E+01 Gap:  3.00E-02
Iter:     3 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    6 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    2 Obj:  1.75E+01 Gap:  3.00E-02
--Integer Solution:   1.75E+01 Lowest Leaf:   1.70E+01 Gap:   3.00E-02
Iter:     4 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    6 Dpth:    2 Lvs:    1 Obj:  2.59E+01 Gap:  3.00E-02
Iter:     5 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    5 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    0 Obj:  2.15E+01 Gap:  3.00E-02
 No additional trial points, returning the best integer solution
 Successful solution

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   1.609999999345746E-002 sec
 Objective      :    17.5322673012512     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------

x1: [1.3589086474]
x2: [4.5992789966]
x3: [4.0]
x4: [1.0]
Objective: 17.532267301
```